# Triggering a jQuery Collapsible when a function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working with the JavaScript API of a desktop software. I have a jQuery `Collapsible` widget that contains a table. This table is created when I click somewhere in my software. By default, the `Collapsible` is collapsed. What I want to do is to uncollapse it automatically (to show the table inside of it) everytime I click somewhere in my software.

In a nutshell : I have a `onSelectionChanged()` method in my API. I want to unfold my `Collapsible` every time I call this function. That differs from the usual process which listens to a given event; I want the `Collapsible` to react as if it was clicked every time I call a given function.

I hope the description of my problem is not unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do using `activate method`([documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)).

```
$("#myaccordion").accordion("activate", 1 );
```

Where 1 is the index you want to open.
You can get the current zero-based index of the active panel by calling:

```
var index = $("#myaccordion").accordion('option','active');  
$("#mybutton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var acc = $("#myaccordion"),
        index = acc.accordion('option', 'active'),
        total = acc.children('div').length,
        nxt = index + 1; // you desider accordion in tis case I am opening next one

    if (nxt >= total) {
        nxt = 0; // Loop around to the first item
    }

    acc.accordion('activate', nxt);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually asking for a `collapsible`, not for an `accordion`, but the option works on `collapsible` too !